# android clear log programmatically

Tags: android, logcat

I want to get the whole log (Log.d(...)), after pressing a button to analyse some parts of our app (count something...). I'm able to do this by the following code:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hashMapToSaveStuff = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
int count= 0;
String toCount= "";
try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("MYSTRING")) {
                toCount = line.substring(line.indexOf(":") + 1);
                if (hashMapToSaveStuff.containsKey(toCount)) {
                    count = hashMapToSaveStuff.get(toCount);
                    count++;
                } else {
                    count= 1;
                }
                hashMapToSaveStuff.put(toCount, count);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

After that I'll send the result to our server and save it on database. Because of that I want to clear all the logs, I've already send. Trying to do this with the following code didn't work:

```
try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()), 1024);
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

How can I clear the log?

Comment: I believe you need to be running with appropriate privileges to clear the log file (or read anything other than the logs from your own process).  The "shell" user has the necessary privileges, which is why it works from adb shell.

Comment: Instead of clearing the log - just apply the timestamp filter https://stackoverflow.com/q/45416946/1778421

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code has worked for me in the past:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder()
     .command("logcat", "-c")
     .redirectErrorStream(true)
     .start();
```

Comment: This did not work for me even with process.waitFor()