# Saving Logcat output of Dalvik VM in external storage

Tags: android, logcat, dalvik

I need to log information relative to dalvikvm, i can see them using the LogCat window but i want to do is to save a particular information into a file.

```
12-29 10:34:47.881: D/dalvikvm(7634): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 23794K, 76% free 11573K/47148K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
12-29 10:34:47.891: I/dalvikvm-heap(7634): Grow heap (frag case) to 34.952MB for 23970832-byte allocation
```

I need to log this so i can say to my customer to save a bitmap it uses 23794k in 14ms ....

But i have no ideas on how to do this.

Thanks, i know this is something special.

Comment: You can see the logcat output for your own app by running the "logcat" command on the device, from your app, and capturing stdout.

Comment: i want my app be able to save this an .txt file for example

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359692/how-to-redirect-my-log-output-from-logcat-to-the-sd-card-on-an-android-device or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678829/android-clear-log-programmatically

Comment: @user2335528 please mark an answer as correct if it helps you, don't just abondon your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `logcat -f <filename>` to save your logs in a file.

also make sure that you provide a correct external storage path for a `<filename>`, you can get the full path of your SD card using, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`.

Example,

```
String sdCARD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String fileName = "logs.txt";
String path = sdCard + fileName;
```

and from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359692/how-to-redirect-my-log-output-from-logcat-to-the-sd-card-on-an-android-device),

> in order to pass arguments to the logcat program, you should pass the
>   exec method an array of strings (and not one string):